# Address form autocomplete type change

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Im implementing googles address form autocomplete, and I have bind it to a map so that when address is inputted and form autofilled map zooms to that location. 
I had to change types in autocomplete object from geocode to locality since map was zooming in the wrong places, but now form filling is not working and I can't figure it why, because all the code is the same except type parameter.

Other thing is that when I leave type at geocode and filling is working, form fields are populated with cyrillic. Why is that.

Can anyone help me with this?

P.S. I didn't posted any code since only change is to type of autocomplete object to locality

[Address form autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `locality`-type .

The types that may be used with an autocomplete are:

- `geocode`
- `establishment`
- `(regions)`
- `(cities)`

...and nothing else.